# What's Lax and Lax2 protocols?

Tags: voip, sip, protocol, asterisk

Are LAX and LAX2 communication protocols like SIP? What are these?
Some telephone systems support them beside SIP but I cannot find information on google

Comment: People using Google Web should find a little more information now. ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find the information because you, or possibly some optical character recognition process, have mis-spelled them.  They are **IAX** (the **i**nter-**A**sterisk e**x**change protocol, designed for communication between Asterisk systems as the name suggests) and **IAX2** (version 2).